# Trilogy Sites used as a Social Engineering Platform for Malware?

Tags: support, questions, answers

I just saw [the following "answer"](https://superuser.com/questions/86809/how-to-download-subtitles-for-ted-talks/87052#87052) in [one of my questions @ SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/86809/how-to-download-subtitles-for-ted-talks):

> yes yes offcourse. try this i guess
>   its have nice tutorial
>   http://tinyurl.com/yevoq55  and
>   password file is
>   h**p://jesicamaiden.myopenid.com/

Is it me or is this some kind of attempt to distribute some kind of malware?

Are these things new in Trilogy sites? Are we looking at a new thread and how can we fight it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is tinyurl and the like permitted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is disturbing!

If you see it, flag it for moderator attention.

Maybe even email us directly via the link at the bottom of each page if this happens again so we can make sure it's removed more urgently than usual.

Comment: I flagged it immediately (well after checking the provided link actually), and the deletion was quite fast but if this spreads I think that something should be done (like using some kind of classification algorithm to determine if it represents a thread, or maybe limit new users on features like adding links) to avoid at least the majority of this kind of stuff.

Comment: @Alix Axel: Actually you have a great point. Does google have an API to their threat list?

Answer (score 5):

I have deleted the offending answer already as I picked up on the flag before I hit meta. I do agree with Jeff that an e-mail to the team or one of the moderators will also assist.

I find on SU that with very popular questions I do have to spend some time when they trickle to the top to do a cleanup of the answers, and this is unavoidable since most SU visitors don't understand the trilogy, or are drive by visitors.

Comment: Thanks Diago, nicely done there. =)